# Seagate Backup Plus Slim 2tb clicking and beeping - shows up in device manager, nowhere else

Tags: hard-drive

***TL;DR*** my hard drive started beeping and clicking and the bios would go slow/hang when the drive is plugged in and only device manager would detect the drive. **is the drive dead?** **(BTW I BOUGHT THIS HARD DRIVE 3 MONTHS AGO)**

A few hours ago, my hard drive started beeping and clicking. I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on the hard drive, and then it suddenly started doing the beeping and clicking. The Ubuntu OS froze up, so I rebooted and it couldn't boot back into Ubuntu. Then I booted into my internal disk, which had Windows 7. It wouldn't recognize the disk except in the device manager. I tried diskpart and SeaTools, but diskpart wouldn't detect any Seagate drive, and SeaTools started hanging and using up a ton of CPU when it was started with the drive plugged in. Also, when I rebooted/booted my computer up, it would hang, and if I try to plug in the drive after it passed the bios logo, the computer would go *really slow*. My computer (laptop) is a thinkpad t440p. what I should do, and is my hard drive really dead? (BTW I BOUGHT THIS HARD DRIVE 3 MONTHS AGO)

=========================

**EDIT:** so far, these are the programs I tried:

GetDataBack

Partition Assistant Lite

PC Inspector File Recovery

HDD Regenerator

Partition Wizard

Hiren's Bootable CD (Used gparted on linux)

Victoria

HDDScan

SeaTools

PROGRAMS THAT AT LEAST DETECT HARD DRIVE 100% OF THE TIME:

***Recuva (ALWAYS DETECTS hard drive, but can't scan it)***

When scanning, it says "*Failed to scan the following drives: \.\HarddiskVolume2: Unable to determine file system type*"

BIOS FREEZES WHEN PLUGGED IN, TESTED ON TWO LAPTOPS

**OTHER PROGRAMS SUCH AS DISK MANAGEMENT OCCASIONALLY DETECT IT (after a while after plugging in or after running recuva, not sure)**

WHEN DETECTED BY DISK MANAGEMENT: Asks for initialization, either option ends up with "*The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error*" If the drive shows up in disk management, then it shows up in most of the other partition/disk tools that I tried

When other programs detect it, such as diskpart, it says the capacity is 0B/0KB/

When HDDRegen detects the drive, it says 0MB in 0 sectors, when when I try to scan it, the program crashes

When Victoria detects the hard drive, it says the size is 0kb, and when i try to test it, it fails immediately

SCREENSHOTS FROM VICTORIA PROGRAM: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGp6b.jpg  https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlzzy.jpg

SMART FROM VICTORIA PROGRAM: *Get S.M.A.R.T. command... Error reading S.M.A.R.T!*

*Also, I force-unplugged the HDD a few times because Safely Remove Hardware kept saying that there was a program using the HDD, even though I killed a bunch of processes and closed all visible and system tray programs that probably would be using the disk. (not sure if that will affect anything)*

## *I didn't see any sign of failure before the hard drive started clicking and beeping*

Comment: Yes (in any case, no linger trustable). But look at the bright side, it must still be under warranty.

Comment: Could you atleast mark my answer or upvote, as this seems dead.

Answer (score 2):

- 95% chance that the drive is damaged. The clicking noise is the sound of the read/write head trying to free itself from the platter where it's trapped. This will almost certainly have damaged the head and the platter because they should never touch each other.

You could try to burn Hirens or a alternative which has "Victoria" or "HDDscan", or just downlaod HDDscan and launch it on the Windows to Seagate disk, if it cant go through simple DISK READ test you can confirm it is dead.

And check the SMART info and TEMP on disk, if TEMP raises above 35-46C it means it is stuck and overheating, which will continue to damage the disk.

To speed up warranty have a screenshot from Victoria/MHDD/HDDSCAN showing bad blocks etc, and a screenshot from bad SMART info, head over to the shop, and get a new one in no time.

Normally with HDD's and other Components, if they work for about 3-5 months they will work indefinitely if not moved :)

Comment: nether Victoria nor HDDScan even detect that the hard drive is plugged in at all (it just doesn't show it),

what does this mean?

Comment: also keep in mind that it does show up in device manager but nowhere else that i have seen

Comment: Can u try to Burn HirensBootCD or PartitionMagick and see if it Shows up in Gparted/SMART info ? It could be that the first sectors have been damaged by unexpected power cut.

Comment: It's dead, Jim. RMA it.

Comment: Well it could be a lead inside the external case has come loose or smthing, i would rather disassemble it and connect it straight into a Desktop/Laptop to see actual results. But as @Overmind said just write down all what you have tried and go to store where you bought it.

Comment: Usually, you can try to connect the drive directly to a SATA port of a computer. If the noise is the same, the verdict is clear. Not easy to do with this model though. 

If you manage to get it to be detectable in BIOS, try further to scan it with HDD regenerator to see if any attempt of bad sectors recovery are made. 

If HDD R partially fixes it and you can access it from within an operating system, try a scan with any scan-disk-like tool and also check SMART attributes.

If you find reallocated or bad sectors, it's still good-to-RMA so you might as well do that from start.

Comment: Note that opening it and removing the drive in order to connect it directly may void warranty. And this is not an easy to surgery model. For other I'd try disassembly, but not for this one.

Comment: @Overmind it will void the warranty

Comment: @dExIT ok now Victoria is always detecting the hard drive, and Recuva is also detecting the hard drive 100% of the time, nothing else really detects it 100% of the time, and none of the programs can scan the drive without errors. When the hard drive is plugged in while the laptop is in the bios or is booting, the laptop hangs until it is unplugged. (More info in main post, i edited it)

Comment: @LapisZ the drive is dead, please say that you are unable to read SMART INFO and The HDD clicks, you will get a replacement 100%